# Automate translations of dynamic content within DB on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a big rails app that's using a custom-made CMS that stores certain page sections in a database. This app also has a translate(string) function that looks up strings in another DB table || google translate API if not found.

Now this setup works great except one little aspect - when switching to another language, static content must also be translated, so for that we just clone the content into different rows.

What I'd like to do is to implement some sort of tag to be used within the template and have the same helper that does the plain translations adjust the strings from within the static template. I'd have users enter tags such as [translate[mary had a little lamb]] and when the page is rendered, the helper would kick in and pull translations from either the DB or google translate API. The helper is already working quite nice, with memcache, CRUD admin pages to manage strings and whatnot.

So basically:

```
<div class="some-random-class">
<p>This is some random text that won't be translated</p>
<p>And the following piece of text will be translated using the helper: [translate[mary had a little lamb]]</p>
</div>
```

Is there a (safe) way to make this happen? Would appreciate any pointers. We have several hundred pages already and cloning them 15 times for each site that runs on this app will be a nightmare.

Later edit: the content is called dynamic in the Q title because it comes from a database. To the end-user however it is static HTML with some text here and there. Sorry if this caused any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick way of doing it:

*In a helper module:*

```
def pretranslate(str)
  md = str.match(/\[translate\[([^\]]*)\]\]/)
  str.gsub(md[0], translate(md[1]))
end
```

*In your controller:*

```
@text = %Q{
  And the following piece of text will be translated using the helper: [translate[mary had a little lamb]]
}
```

*In your view:*

```
<%= pretranslate(@text) %>
```

This is obviously pretty hacky. It's not really safe by nature, but shouldn't be too dangerous, depending on what you do with the input in your `translate` method.

Comment: Content is trusted so are the users so 99.99% sure nothing can happen... at least not now. But you are right that this sort of hack should never be done on a public-facing site. And a small note, using str.scan instead of str.match will return all matches which is good in this case. TYVM for your help!