# Somewhat complex ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a bunch of strings I translate within views of a CMS as follows:

```
<a href="blah">[translate[This is the best website in the whole wide world!]]</a>
```

This works great thanks to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143561/automate-translations-of-dynamic-content-within-db-on-rails) however I would like to take it to the next step and use tags such as [website_name] inside the [translate[........]] tags. Doing so with the current regexp skips the fragment.

This is what I am using now:

```
(/\[translate\[([^\]]*)\]\]/)
```

Is it possible to make this ignore any [tags] inside? Basically I am trying to make it stop at ]] instead of anything else.

so basically for [translate[This is the best [product] in the whole wide world!]] the output would be This is the best [product] in the whole wide world!

TIA

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: for [translate[This is the best [product] in the whole wide world!]] the output would be This is the best [product] in the whole wide world!

Comment: just replace `website` with `[product]`

Comment: it does not return anything. because of the square brackets inside, precisely the 2nd

Comment: Have you considered using I18n?

Comment: Yes, and several other less popular alternatives, this CMS has a lot of non-standard functionality so it all got built from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a recursive regular expression here.

```
\[translate\[((?:[^\[\]]++|\[\g<1>\])++)\]\]
```

[**Rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/bbMLcZDhF9) (Ruby 1.9.2)+

If you are using (Ruby 1.8.7), as stated in the comments:

```
\[translate\[((?>[^\[\]]+|\[\g<1>\])*)\]\]
```

Comment: Looks good in the sandbox but the ruby regular expression compiler doesn't like it, syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'

Comment: Is there a way to make it work on both ruby 2.0.0 and ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: @NickM: Yes, you can write it without possessive quantifiers using an atomic group instead: `\[translate\[((?>[^\[\]]+|\[\g<1>\])*)\]\]`

Comment: This one returns no match

Comment: I think I'm going to find an alternative though, see what happens with the previous tags - http://rubular.com/r/GA6bvAki7e . I'm thinking to temporarily replace the tags with something else, translate, then replace back to the square bracket tags..

Comment: @NickM the reason it matches everything inside `[translate[ .. ]]` is because it's a recursive regex. It will be hard to stop at the first set of nested brackets in 1.8. It does work in 2.0.0 and above, see [example](http://rubular.com/r/oErWnHx3tV)